# Complex exponential plot

Tags: plotting, complex

I don't know how to plot the exponential of an imaginary number. The function I've to plot is: `Exp[-I w t]`. I can give w a number, so I've chose w=1 and:

```
Plot [E^ [-I t], {t, -20, 20}]
```

but it shows nothing.

Comment: try `ReImPlot[Exp[-I t], {t, -20, 20}]` or `ReImPlot[E^(-I t), {t, -20, 20}]`?

Comment: `Exp[I t]` as a function of t is a number on the unit circle. With increasing t, the number circulates clockwise around the origin. And `Exp[-I t]` anti clockwise. Therefore plotting `ReIm` gives `Sin`and `Cos` functions of `t`.

Comment: Use `ParametricPlot[ReIm@Exp[I t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]` to obtain an Argand diagram of $e^{i t}$.

Answer (score 1):

The old school way is to plot the `Re` and `Im` part separately. Or you can plot them parametrically as @LouisB suggested.

```
f[t_] = Exp[-I t]
Plot[{Re[f[t]], Im[f[t]]}, {t, -20, 20}]
ParametricPlot[{Re[f[t]], Im[f[t]]}, {t, -20, 20}, AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im"}]
```

[image]

If you are using V12, then you can use `ReImPlot`

```
ReImPlot[f[t], {t, -20, 20}]
```

[image]